# How can I pull multiple rows from containers while using a loop for multiple containers in BS4?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/injuries/nba/all/ for current NBA injury data. I've written a python script (below), which is correctly pulling the teams and the first row of the data for each team container, but not all of the players per container. I'm very new to Python, but have spent a lot of time trying to find a solution and unfortunately have not found anything to solve the problem. I hope this isn't too novice of a question!

Could someone please help me pull all of the player data for each team?

Also, if there's any additional recommendations on improving my script, please let me know! I'm so excited to have finally started working in Python!

Thank you in advance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


#Define URL to fetch
url = 'http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/injuries/nba/all/'

#Make requests
data = requests.get(url)

# To force American English (en-US) when necessary
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

#Create BeautifulSoup object
soup = bs(data.text, 'html.parser')

# Lists to store scraped data
teams = []
players = []
reports = []
return_dates = []
injury_dates = []
injuries = []
positions = []
statuses = []

# Extract data from individual containers

    for container in team_containers:

    # Team Name
    team = container.a.text
    teams.append(team)

    # Player Name [First, Last]
    player = container.table.a.text
    players.append(player)

    # Player Report
    report = container.find('div', attrs = { 'class':'report'}).text
    reports.append(report)

    # Player Return
    return_date = container.find('div', attrs = { 'class':'impact'}).text
    return_dates.append(return_date)

    # Player Injury Dates
    injury_date = container.find('div', attrs = { 'class':'date'}).text
    injury_dates.append(injury_date)

    # Player Injury Details
    injury = container.find('div', attrs = { 'class':'playercard'}).span.text
    injuries.append(injury)

    # Player Position
    position= container.table.find_all('td')[9].text
    positions.append(position)

    # Player Status
    status = container.table.find_all('td')[10].text
    statuses.append(status)

import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'team': teams,
                       'player': players,
                       'report': reports,
                       'return_date': return_dates,
                       'injury_date': injury_dates,
                       'injury': injuries,
                       'position': positions,
                       'status': statuses})
print(test_df.info())
test_df
```

Current results: 
* 27 Containers - one per team (if team has 1+ injury), containing first player in the team's table
* Name, Report, POS, Date, Injury, Returns as fields recorded

Expected results: 
* 27 Containers - one per team (if team has 1+ injury), containing all players in the team's table
* Name, Report, POS, Date, Injury, Returns as header rows and fields recorded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you notice that html codes have a `<table>` tag, you can have Pandas do a lot of the work with `.read_html()`

So I worked it out this way, using Pandas to get the tables. The only problem I had then, was to get the Team name in there. So I used BeautifulSoup to get the Team names into a list in the order that the tables appear, and then match that up with the list of dataframes Panda returns.

So I'll put both versions here: 1) without Team Name, 2) with Team name:

**Without Team Name**

```
import pandas as pd   

url = 'http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/injuries/nba/all/'

# Get All Tables
tables = pd.read_html(url)

results = pd.DataFrame()
for table in tables:
    temp_df = table[1:]
    temp_df.columns = table.iloc[0]
    temp_df = temp_df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')

    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
0                      Name            ...                              Returns
0             Kent Bazemore            ...                Targeting mid-January
1            Taurean Prince            ...                           Day-to-day
2   Rondae Hollis-Jefferson            ...                           Day-to-day
3               Dzanan Musa            ...                           Day-to-day
4              Allen Crabbe            ...                Targeting mid-January
5              Caris LeVert            ...                   Targeting February
6             Marcus Morris            ...                           Day-to-day
7              Kyrie Irving            ...                           Day-to-day
8           Robert Williams            ...                           day-to-day
9               Aron Baynes            ...                    Targeting MLK Day
10               Malik Monk            ...                           Day-to-day
11              Cody Zeller            ...             Targeting All-Star break
12              Jeremy Lamb            ...                           day-to-day
13             Bobby Portis            ...                Targeting mid-January
14         Denzel Valentine            ...                       Out for season
15      Matthew Dellavedova            ...                           Day-to-day
16               Ante Zizic            ...                           Day-to-day
17              David Nwaba            ...                           Day-to-day
18               J.R. Smith            ...                     Out indefinitely
19              John Henson            ...                     Out Indefinitely
20               Kevin Love            ...                Targeting mid-January
21              Will Barton            ...                         week-to-week
22        Jarred Vanderbilt            ...                     Out indefinitely
23       Michael Porter Jr.            ...                     Out indefinitely
24            Isaiah Thomas            ...                   Targeting December
25            Zaza Pachulia            ...                           Day-to-day
26                Ish Smith            ...                     Out Indefinitely
27           Henry Ellenson            ...                     Out indefinitely
28             Damian Jones            ...                     Out Indefinitely
29         DeMarcus Cousins            ...                   Targeting January?
..                      ...            ...                                  ...


[74 rows x 6 columns]
```

### Include A Column With Team Name

```
import bs4
import requests 
import pandas as pd   

url = 'http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/injuries/nba/all/'

#Make requests
data = requests.get(url)

# To force American English (en-US) when necessary
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

#Create BeautifulSoup object
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
```

When I "Inspect" the page/html, I notice the team name appears under the tag `<div class "player">`, which is right before the `<table`> tag. So that tells me the Team Name text proceeds their table (and it's obvious in the display on the site too)
So I find all the tags with `<div class "player">` and store them in `team_containers`

```
team_containers =  soup.find_all('div', {'class':'player'})
```

If I print the length `print (len(team_containers))` I see there's 27 elements. If I look at the length of `tables` after doing `tables = pd.read_html(url)`, I'll also get back 27. So this might not all ways be the case, but I'm confident in my assumptions that 27 elements with the `team_containers`, and 27 dataframes in the `tables`, means they should match up, and should also be in the same order.

So next, I iterate through the `team_containers` to pull out the text, and put that into a list. I used list comprehension, but you very well could just do a `for` loop:

```
teams = [ team.text for team in team_containers ]
```

is the same as:

```
teams = []
for team in team_containers:
    teams.append(team.text)
```

which gives me elements in a list:

```
['Atlanta Hawks', 'Brooklyn Nets', 'Boston Celtics', 'Charlotte Hornets', 'Chicago Bulls', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', 'Denver Nuggets', 'Detroit Pistons', 'Golden State Warriors', 'Houston Rockets', 'Indiana Pacers', 'Los Angeles Clippers', 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'Memphis Grizzlies', 'Miami Heat', 'Minnesota Timberwolves', 'Milwaukee Bucks', 'New Orleans Pelicans', 'New York Knicks', 'Oklahoma City Thunder', 'Orlando Magic', 'Philadelphia 76ers', 'San Antonio Spurs', 'Sacramento Kings', 'Toronto Raptors', 'Utah Jazz', 'Washington Wizards']
```

You have to understand that each element in a list has an index/position, starting at 0. So `'Atlanta Hawks'` would be `teams[0]`, `'Brooklyn Nets'` is `teams[1]`, etc.

I initialize a final `results` dataframe, start my index/position at 0, to append all the tables into one `results` and to iterate through my `teams` list while iterating through the `tables`.

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
```

And then iterate through my `tables`

```
for table in tables:
```

right now my index is a 0 (which is the `'Atlanta Hawks'`). I store that in a variable called team.

```
    team = teams[idx]
```

I want all rows in my table, except the first row since its the headers. I store that as some temporary dataframe which I called `temp_df` to work with and later append to my results.

```
    temp_df = table[1:]
```

I name the headers/columns of `temp_df`, that first row from `table`

```
    temp_df.columns = table.iloc[0]
```

I rename the second column of `temp_df` because it's 'Nan' (it's actually the spot where the report is on the site, but it doesn't pull that, and figure I'll just use that as my `"Team"` column

```
    temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={ temp_df.columns[1]: "Team" })
```

I assign `'Atlanta Hawks'` as that value so that `"Team"` column is filled with `'Atlanta Hawks'`

```
    temp_df['Team'] = team
```

And now that I'm done with that, on the next iteration, I want the next index position in my teams list, so I increment it by 1, so the next loop will be `'teams[1]'` which will be the `'Brooklyn Nets'` table

```
    idx += 1
```

And append that temporary dataframe into my final results one. Then it goes through that process again, on the next element in my `tables` and now with my index set as 1 so that it'll populate `'Brooklyn Nets'` as my `team` variable

```
    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So Full Code:

```
import bs4
import requests 
import pandas as pd   

url = 'http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/injuries/nba/all/'

#Make requests
data = requests.get(url)

# To force American English (en-US) when necessary
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}

#Create BeautifulSoup object
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

# Get Team Names in Order as Tables Appear
team_containers =  soup.find_all('div', {'class':'player'})
teams = [ team.text for team in team_containers ]

# Get All Tables
tables = pd.read_html(url)

results = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0
for table in tables:
    team = teams[idx]

    temp_df = table[1:]
    temp_df.columns = table.iloc[0]
    temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={ temp_df.columns[1]: "Team" })
    temp_df['Team'] = team

    idx += 1

    results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print(results)
0                      Name            ...                              Returns
0             Kent Bazemore            ...                Targeting mid-January
1            Taurean Prince            ...                           Day-to-day
2   Rondae Hollis-Jefferson            ...                           Day-to-day
3               Dzanan Musa            ...                           Day-to-day
4              Allen Crabbe            ...                Targeting mid-January
5              Caris LeVert            ...                   Targeting February
6             Marcus Morris            ...                           Day-to-day
7              Kyrie Irving            ...                           Day-to-day
8           Robert Williams            ...                           day-to-day
9               Aron Baynes            ...                    Targeting MLK Day
10               Malik Monk            ...                           Day-to-day
11              Cody Zeller            ...             Targeting All-Star break
12              Jeremy Lamb            ...                           day-to-day
13             Bobby Portis            ...                Targeting mid-January
14         Denzel Valentine            ...                       Out for season
15      Matthew Dellavedova            ...                           Day-to-day
16               Ante Zizic            ...                           Day-to-day
17              David Nwaba            ...                           Day-to-day
18               J.R. Smith            ...                     Out indefinitely
19              John Henson            ...                     Out Indefinitely
20               Kevin Love            ...                Targeting mid-January
21              Will Barton            ...                         week-to-week
22        Jarred Vanderbilt            ...                     Out indefinitely
23       Michael Porter Jr.            ...                     Out indefinitely
24            Isaiah Thomas            ...                   Targeting December
25            Zaza Pachulia            ...                           Day-to-day
26                Ish Smith            ...                     Out Indefinitely
27           Henry Ellenson            ...                     Out indefinitely
28             Damian Jones            ...                     Out Indefinitely
29         DeMarcus Cousins            ...                   Targeting January?
..                      ...            ...                                  ...


[74 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to share all this, @chitown88! I was unaware that I could use:
    
    # Get All Tables
    tables = pd.read_html(url). 
    
Would you mind explaining how the code under "for table in tables" section works? I.e.,    
    
     team = teams[idx]

    temp_df = table[1:]
    temp_df.columns = table.iloc[0]
    temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={ temp_df.columns[1]: "Team" })
    temp_df['Team'] = team

Comment: yes. it saves a lot of time with having to iterate through rows and data when the html is nice with the table tags. Just need to clean it up a bit by making the first row the header, eliminating any Null rows, etc. But I find that easier than iterating through <tr> and <td> tags. Just keep in mind for the future it returns the tables as a list of dataframes. So you may need to search through that list to grab a particular table, or to merge/join/append a bunch a dataframes/tables from the site

Comment: sure, I'll edit above to go through it. hopefully it'll make sense

Comment: I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

below code is selecting first element

```
player = container.table.a.text
```

you need loop to get all player

```
# Player Name [First, Last]
for player in container.select('table a'):
    if player.text: # skip "a img"
        players.append(player.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ewwink! Should would I also need to create a loop for the other fields as well, in order to ensure that data is collected for each player?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the `div`s containing each team with its corresponding player listings:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
d = soup(requests.get('http://www.rotoworld.com/teams/injuries/nba/all/').text, 'html.parser')
def team_data(_content:soup) -> list:
  _team_name = _content.find('div', {'class':'headline'}).text
  _all_results = [[i.text for i in b.find_all('td') if i.text] for b in _content.find_all('tr')]
  return {'team':_team_name, 'results':_all_results}

final_results = [team_data(i) for i in d.find('div', {'id':'cp1_pnlInjuries'}).find_all('div', {'class':'pb'})]
```

Output:

```
[{'team': 'Atlanta Hawks', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Kent Bazemore', 'ankleKent Bazemore (right ankle) will miss at least the next two weeks of action for Atlanta.Targeting mid-JanuaryDec\xa030', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa029', 'ankle', 'Targeting mid-January'], ['Taurean Prince', "ankleTaurean Prince (left ankle) will remain on the sidelines for Wednesday's game in Washington.Day-to-dayJan\xa01", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa03', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'Brooklyn Nets', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Rondae Hollis-Jefferson', "groinRondae Hollis-Jefferson (right adductor strain) has been ruled out for Friday's game vs. Memphis.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa029', 'groin', 'Day-to-day'], ['Dzanan Musa', 'shoulderDzanan Musa was diagnosed on Monday with a left shoulder subluxation.Day-to-dayDec\xa017', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa017', 'shoulder', 'Day-to-day'], ['Allen Crabbe', 'kneeThe Nets announced Allen Crabbe (knee) will be re-evaluated in 1-2 weeks.Targeting mid-JanuaryJan\xa02', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa013', 'knee', 'Targeting mid-January'], ['Caris LeVert', 'footCaris LeVert (foot) has been doing some on-court work and is on schedule according to the rehab team.Targeting FebruaryDec\xa014', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa011', 'foot', 'Targeting February']]}, {'team': 'Boston Celtics', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Marcus Morris', "neckMarcus Morris (neck) is questionable for Friday's game vs. Dallas.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'neck', 'Day-to-day'], ['Kyrie Irving', 'eyeKyrie Irving (left eye inflammation) will not play vs. the Mavs on Friday.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa031', 'eye', 'Day-to-day'], ['Robert Williams', 'groinRobert Williams (groin) is questionable vs. the Mavericks on Thursday.day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa027', 'groin', 'day-to-day'], ['Aron Baynes', 'handAron Baynes (left hand) had surgery to repair a fracture to his fourth metacarpal and he will be out 4-6 weeks.Targeting MLK DayDec\xa020', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa019', 'hand', 'Targeting MLK Day']]}, {'team': 'Charlotte Hornets', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Malik Monk', "ankleMalik Monk (left ankle sprain) exited Wednesday's game in the first half, going scoreless with one rebound and one block in just five minutes.Day-to-dayJan\xa02", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Cody Zeller', 'handCody Zeller underwent successful surgery on the third metacarpal of his right hand Thursday afternoon.Targeting All-Star breakJan\xa03', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa031', 'hand', 'Targeting All-Star break'], ['Jeremy Lamb', "hamstringJeremy Lamb (right hamstring) has been ruled out for Wednesday's game vs. Dallas.day-to-dayJan\xa02", 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa031', 'hamstring', 'day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'Chicago Bulls', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Bobby Portis', "ankleBobby Portis (sprained right ankle) went through a full practice on Thursday, though he's listed as 'doubtful' on the official injury report.Targeting mid-JanuaryJan\xa03", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa019', 'ankle', 'Targeting mid-January'], ['Denzel Valentine', 'ankleDenzel Valentine underwent a left ankle stabilization procedure on Tuesday and he will be out for the 2018-19 season.Out for seasonNov\xa028', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Apr\xa03', 'ankle', 'Out for season']]}, {'team': 'Cleveland Cavaliers', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Matthew Dellavedova', "footMatthew Dellavedova (sprained left foot) is listed as questionable for Friday's game vs. Utah.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa03', 'foot', 'Day-to-day'], ['Ante Zizic', 'kneeAnte Zizic (right knee soreness) will not play on Friday.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa027', 'knee', 'Day-to-day'], ['David Nwaba', "ankleDavid Nwaba (left ankle) has been ruled out for Friday's game.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa023', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['J.R. Smith', 'undisclosedAccording to Marc Stein of the New York Times, the Rockets "have expressed exploratory interest in acquiring JR Smith."Out indefinitelyDec\xa010', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa028', 'undisclosed', 'Out indefinitely'], ['John Henson', 'wristJohn Henson has been traded to the Cavs.Out IndefinitelyDec\xa07', 'F/C', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa015', 'wrist', 'Out Indefinitely'], ['Kevin Love', 'toeKevin Love (left foot surgery) will now progress with select basketball activities and continue to advance his therapy and strength and conditioning program.Targeting mid-JanuaryJan\xa03', 'F/C', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa025', 'toe', 'Targeting mid-January']]}, {'team': 'Denver Nuggets', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Will Barton', 'hipWill Barton (hip) is out for Thursday night against the Kings.week-to-weekJan\xa02', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa020', 'hip', 'week-to-week'], ['Jarred Vanderbilt', 'footPer Nuggets\' head coach Mike Malone, Jarred Vanderbilt (foot) is still "a ways away" from being able to practice.Out indefinitelyOct\xa028', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Sep\xa030', 'foot', 'Out indefinitely'], ['Michael Porter Jr.', "backMichael Porter Jr. (back surgery) has been ruled out for Wednesday's regular-season opener against the Clippers.Out indefinitelyOct\xa016", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Jul\xa07', 'back', 'Out indefinitely'], ['Isaiah Thomas', 'hipAccording to Mike Singer of the Denver Post, Isaiah Thomas (hip) is targeting a return at some point in December.Targeting DecemberDec\xa03', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Mar\xa024', 'hip', 'Targeting December']]}, {'team': 'Detroit Pistons', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Zaza Pachulia', 'legZaza Pachulia (leg contusion) will not play on Wednesday.Day-to-dayJan\xa02', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'leg', 'Day-to-day'], ['Ish Smith', 'groinIsh Smith is making good progress in his recovery from a strained right groin and he will be re-evaluated next week.Out IndefinitelyJan\xa02', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa05', 'groin', 'Out Indefinitely'], ['Henry Ellenson', "ankleHenry Ellenson (left ankle) will remain on the sidelines for Tuesday's game against the Bucks.Out indefinitelyJan\xa01", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa018', 'ankle', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Golden State Warriors', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Damian Jones', 'pectoralsDamian Jones (torn left pectoral) acknowledged on Sunday that he will likely miss the rest of the season.Out IndefinitelyDec\xa09', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa01', 'pectorals', 'Out Indefinitely'], ['DeMarcus Cousins', 'achillesDeMarcus Cousins (Achilles) went through a full practice on Wednesday.Targeting January?Jan\xa02', 'F/C', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa026', 'achilles', 'Targeting January?']]}, {'team': 'Houston Rockets', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Eric Gordon', 'kneeEric Gordon (knee) will not play on Thursday against the Warriors.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa029', 'knee', 'Day-to-day'], ['Chris Paul', 'hamstringAsked when he\'ll return to game action, Chris Paul (hamstring) said he has "no clue."Out indefinitelyJan\xa01', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa020', 'hamstring', 'Out indefinitely'], ['Carmelo Anthony', 'restThe Wizards, Lakers, 76ers and Hornets are not interested in making a move for Carmelo Anthony.Out indefinitelyDec\xa026', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa010', 'rest', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Indiana Pacers', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Aaron Holiday', "illnessAaron Holiday (illness) is questionable for Friday's game against the Bulls.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa03', 'illness', 'Day-to-day'], ['Doug McDermott', "ankleDoug McDermott (ankle) is not being listed on the injury report for Friday's game in Chicago.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa031', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Myles Turner', "noseMyles Turner (broken nose) was a full participant at Thursday's practice and is being listed as questionable for Friday's game in Chicago.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'F/C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa031', 'nose', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'Los Angeles Clippers', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Luc Mbah a Moute', "kneeLuc Mbah a Moute (left knee) won't play on Thursday.Out indefinitelyDec\xa013", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa05', 'knee', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Kyle Kuzma', "backKyle Kuzma (bruised lower back) is questionable for Friday's game vs. the Knicks.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'back', 'Day-to-day'], ['Rajon Rondo', 'handAccording to Shams Charania of The Athletic, Rajon Rondo is expected to undergo surgery on his injured right hand and miss at least one month.Day-to-dayDec\xa028', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa026', 'hand', 'Day-to-day'], ['LeBron James', "groinLeBron James (left groin) is listed 'out' for Friday's game vs. the Knicks.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa025', 'groin', 'Day-to-day'], ['Michael Beasley', "personalMichael Beasley (personal) has been ruled out of Friday's game vs. the Knicks.Out indefinitelyJan\xa04", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa014', 'personal', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Memphis Grizzlies', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Mike Conley', "shoulderMike Conley (left shoulder) is listed as questionable for Friday's game vs. the Nets.day-to-dayJan\xa04", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'shoulder', 'day-to-day'], ['Chandler Parsons', 'kneeChandler Parsons (knee) said he is healthy and is "dying to play."Out indefinitelyDec\xa029', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa022', 'knee', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Miami Heat', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Dwyane Wade', "illnessDwyane Wade (illness) is listed as questionable for Friday's game vs. the Wizards.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'illness', 'Day-to-day'], ['Goran Dragic', "kneeGoran Dragic is set to undergo arthroscopic knee surgery on Wednesday and he's expected to miss the next two months of action.Targeting Feb. 21Dec\xa019", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa012', 'knee', 'Targeting Feb. 21']]}, {'team': 'Minnesota Timberwolves', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Robert Covington', "ankleRobert Covington (sore right ankle) has been ruled out for Friday's game vs. Orlando.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa01', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Derrick Rose', "ankleDerrick Rose (sprained right ankle) is doubtful for Friday's game vs. the Magic.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa028', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Jeff Teague', 'ankleJeff Teague (left ankle inflammation) is questionable vs. the Magic on Friday.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa017', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'Milwaukee Bucks', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Sterling Brown', "ankleSterling Brown (right ankle sprain) is listed as probable for Friday's game vs. the Hawks.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa03', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Ersan Ilyasova', "faceErsan Ilyasova (nose) is not listed on the injury report for Friday's game vs. the Hawks.Out indefinitelyJan\xa04", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa017', 'face', 'Out indefinitely'], ['Trevon Duval', "eyeTrevon Duval (eye) will not play in Wednesday's season opener against the Hornets.Day-to-dayOct\xa017", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa017', 'eye', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'New Orleans Pelicans', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Nikola Mirotic', "ankleNikola Mirotic (right ankle) has been ruled out for Wednesday's game in Brooklyn.Day-to-dayJan\xa01", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa010', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'New York Knicks', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Mitchell Robinson', 'ankleMitchell Robinson (left ankle) is questionable for Friday against the Lakers.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa014', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Kristaps Porzingis', 'kneeKnicks\' president Steve Mills stated during a recent interview that Kristaps Porzingis (knee) is still "a ways away" from getting back to the court.Questionable or seasonDec\xa026', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Feb\xa06', 'knee', 'Questionable or season']]}, {'team': 'Oklahoma City Thunder', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Alex Abrines', "personalAlex Abrines (personal) has been ruled out of Friday's game vs. the Blazers.Day-to-dayJan\xa04", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa025', 'personal', 'Day-to-day'], ['Andre Roberson', 'kneeAndre Roberson (left knee) suffered another setback in his rehab and will be sidelined for at least six more weeks.Targeting JanuaryNov\xa030', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa027', 'knee', 'Targeting January']]}, {'team': 'Orlando Magic', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Khem Birch', 'wife having babyKhem Birch is leaving the Magic on Wednesday to join his wife for the birth of their child.Day-to-dayJan\xa02', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'wife having baby', 'Day-to-day'], ['Jonathon Simmons', 'ankleJonathon Simmons (left ankle) is "questionable/probable" for Friday\'s game vs. Minnesota.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa030', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day'], ['Timofey Mozgov', 'kneeTimofey Mozgov (knee) is still out and remains without a timetable.Out indefinitelyDec\xa03', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa021', 'knee', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Philadelphia 76ers', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Joel Embiid', "kneeJoel Embiid (sore left knee) finished Wednesday's road win in Phoenix with 42 points, 17 rebounds, three steals, two assists, two blocks and one 3-pointer, making 12-of-23 FGs and 17-of-19 FGs.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'knee', 'Day-to-day'], ['Wilson Chandler', "illnessWilson Chandler (upper respiratory infection) has been ruled out for Wednesday's game against the Suns.Day-to-dayJan\xa02", 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'illness', 'Day-to-day'], ['Jimmy Butler', 'illnessJimmy Butler (upper respiratory infection) is being listed as "out" for Wednesday\'s game in Phoenix.Day-to-dayJan\xa02', 'G/F', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa02', 'illness', 'Day-to-day'], ['Markelle Fultz', "shoulderMarkelle Fultz's agent, Raymond Brothers, said he expects Fultz to make it back to the court at some point this season.Out IndefinitelyDec\xa025", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa020', 'shoulder', 'Out Indefinitely'], ['Zhaire Smith', 'footZhaire Smith (left foot) has been in the gym working every morning and is expected to play this season, according to GM Elton Brand.Targeting 2019Dec\xa022', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jun\xa04', 'foot', 'Targeting 2019'], ['Justin Patton', 'footJustin Patton has been traded to the 76ers as part of the Jimmy Butler deal.Out indefinitelyNov\xa010', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Apr\xa018', 'foot', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'San Antonio Spurs', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Dejounte Murray', 'kneeDejounte Murray (knee) had successful surgery last Friday to repair the torn ACL in his right knee.Out indefinitelyOct\xa023', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Oct\xa07', 'knee', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Sacramento Kings', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Marvin Bagley', 'kneeMarvin Bagley (left knee) will not play on Thursday.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'F/C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa014', 'knee', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'Toronto Raptors', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Kyle Lowry', 'backKyle Lowry (back) will not play vs. the Spurs on Thursday.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa026', 'back', 'Day-to-day'], ['Jonas Valanciunas', 'thumbJonas Valanciunas (thumb) will miss at least another 3-4 weeks of action.Out indefinitelyJan\xa02', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa012', 'thumb', 'Out indefinitely']]}, {'team': 'Utah Jazz', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Ricky Rubio', "footRicky Rubio (sore left foot) is questionable for Friday's game.Day-to-dayJan\xa03", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Jan\xa03', 'foot', 'Day-to-day'], ['Grayson Allen', "ankleGrayson Allen (ankle) will remain on the sidelines for Tuesday's game vs. Toronto.Day-to-dayDec\xa031", 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa024', 'ankle', 'Day-to-day']]}, {'team': 'Washington Wizards', 'results': [['Name', 'POS', 'Status', 'Date', 'Injury', 'Returns'], ['Markieff Morris', 'backMarkieff Morris has been diagnosed with transient cervical neuropraxia and he will be limited to non-contact work for the next six weeks.Day-to-dayJan\xa03', 'F', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa028', 'back', 'Day-to-day'], ['John Wall', 'heelJohn Wall (left heel) will undergo a debridement and repair of a Haglund’s deformity and a chronic Achilles tendon injury in his left heel.out for seasonDec\xa029', 'G', 'Sidelined', 'Dec\xa028', 'heel', 'out for season'], ['Dwight Howard', 'backDwight Howard said he is now pain-free after undergoing a lumbar microdiscectomy back on Nov. 30.Out indefinitelyDec\xa020', 'C', 'Sidelined', 'Nov\xa018', 'back', 'Out indefinitely']]}]
```